# Ruby on Rails: MiniTest for email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

This is an absolute beginners question, it's probably pretty obvious but I couldn't find the answer yet.

I'm trying to validate an email address in Ruby on Rails using minitest.

```
test "should have format of email address" do
    user = User.create(name: "Dummy", last_name: "Dummy", email: "example.com")
    assert_match(/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, user.email)
    assert_equal ["is invalid"], user.errors[:email]
end
```

The problem occurs in the last line `assert_equal ["is invalid"], user.errors[:email]`.

The email address `example.com` isn't matched by the regex on purpose since I want to check the error message "is invalid" against the one of the failed test but I can't figure out how to pass it into `assert_equal`:

Error Message:

```
Expected /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i to match "example.com".
```

Should be:

```
'is invalid.'
```

Maybe I am wrong, but I my understanding was that error messages of the object could be found in object.errors[:symbol].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually occurs on the second line:

```
assert_match(/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, user.email)
```

The email you are using is "example.com", and it fails the REGEXP match. Try using something like "dummy@example.com" instead.

Comment: I actually want to check if the error message is correct (should be: `is invalid`. That's why I purposely have this test failing (by passing it an incorrect email address). I was pretty sure that the error message would appear in `user.errors[:email]` but that doesn't seem to be true. That's why I compare the two error messages in the last line.

Comment: Then you should split those two asserts into two separate test methods. The assert_match is failing and the assert_equal is not ever run.